# Focus event not fired on focusable parent HTML element with display flex, in IE11, when one of its children is clicked

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11, onfocus

[Here](https://codepen.io/lipata/pen/GBjYPK) is updated (more isolated sample) of the problem in IE11. When parent element (which has tabindex=0 and its display is flex) has child element which is `<div>` or `<span>`, then clicking the text inside in IE11 will not trigger focus event. This is working fine in other browsers and also is working with IE11 and children that are `<p>` or `<section>`. Thanks to @ConnorsFan one of the solutions is to use `display: block` on the parent instead of `display: flex`. However this seems a bug in IE11.

ORIGNAL POST:

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vydxse) is a simple custom HTML component, created using Angular, which has one HTML DIV child with text inside. The component is focusable (it has tabindex=0), however clicking on the text will not fire the focus event in Internet Explorer 11. This is working fine with all other browsers, which makes me think this is bug in IE11. It seems in IE11 something is preventing the focus to be fired on the parent focusable element, while clicking on the child one, which is not focusable.

Replacing [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focus) with [focusin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusin) and using stopPropagation() may be an option, but it is not working either and event is propagated (uncomment focusin hostListener). I need focus to be fired only on the custom component.

Comment: Do you absolutely need the flexbox? It appears to work when setting the display to `block` or `inline-block` with `:host.div-class { display: block; border: 1px solid black; }`.

Comment: Thank you, @ConnorsFan! It works. I'm still wondering why the combination of :host (which is not needed for the styles to be applied properly) and display:block will cause the focus event to fire? When display is block then child div will take parent dimension and it seems in IE11 this somehow is ok with the focus event? But why in addition the :host is needed in that case?

Comment: Ok, the problem with IE11 and display:flex is available on plain HTML div, outside angular project, and here it is isolated (codepen.io/lipata/pen/GBjYPK). I've update the original post above. The :host was needed because I've put styles for the parent host inside the div.component.css, which is not correct, and now I move it in the app.component.css, where it should be. So the :host was needed because of a problem in the sample, which I corrected. @ConnorsFan if you want you can post an answer and I will verify it (without the :host). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my tests on IE11 with [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uccmcn), the focus event is triggered when the `display` style attribute of the child component is set to `block` or `inline-block`, instead of `flex`:

```
.div-class {
    display: block; 
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   import {  Component, OnInit, HostListener, HostBinding} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-div',
  template: `<div (focus)="onFocus($emit)">Click to see some magic happen :)</div>`,
  styles: [`.div-class { display: flex; border: 1px solid black; }`]
})
export class DivComponent  {
    @HostBinding('attr.tabindex')
    public tabindex = 0;

    @HostBinding('attr.class')
      get hostClass(): string {
        return 'div-class';
      }

    @HostListener('focus', ['$event'])
    //@HostListener('focusin', ['$event'])
    public onFocus(event) {
      console.log("focus my-div", document.activeElement);
      // event.stopPropagation();
    }

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    public onClick(event) {
      // console.log("click HostListener");
    }
}
```

I have fixed your div.component.ts file you have to invoke the onFocus() from the div binding it as a one way method and emit the event
checkout the stackbiltz example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gm4hyf

Comment: Thank you! I've already did this, but this is not an option either. The problem is that  I need to have the event handler on the custom element, because it is template-able and someone could replace the <div (focus)="onFocus($emit)"> and therefore it will not work. What I want to understand, at the first place, is if this is a bug in IE11. Thank you, anyway!